# parsing lspci tree using regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

```
$ lspci -tv | grep -E 'Gigabit Network|Gigabit Ether| Ethernet' | grep -oP '(?<=^).*(?=Intel)'
           +-01.0-[01-04]----00.0-[02-04]--+-01.0-[03]--+-00.0  
           |                               |            +-00.1  
           |                               |            +-00.2  
           |                               |            \-00.3  
           |                               \-03.0-[04]--+-00.0  
           |                                            \-00.1  
           +-1c.0-[05]----00.0  
           +-1c.1-[06]----00.0
```

I am trying to get the NIC ordering (slot) using the PCI bus address from this tree. These are represented as the last regex `\[[0-9a-ZA-Z]\]` on a given line, e.g., `[03],[04],[05]` and then sub-headers that follows them, e.g., `00.0, 00.1, 00.2` for `[03]`.

My expected output should be :

```
03:00.0
03:00.1
03:00.2
03:00.3  
04:00.0
04:00.1   
05:00.0
06:00.0
```

For example, I tried this, but haven't gone any further. I know it's ugly and any solution with or without `pipes` would do.

```
$ lspci -tv | grep -E 'Gigabit Network|Gigabit Ether| Ethernet' | grep -oP '(?<=\-).*(?=Intel)'  | grep -oE '(\[[0-9a-ZA-Z]{2}\])|(\[[0-9a-ZA-Z]{2}\].*[0-9]{2}\.[0-9])|(^[0-0]{2}.[0-9])'
[03]--+-00.0
00.1
00.2
00.3
[04]--+-00.0
00.1
[05]----00.0
[06]----00.0
```

Output of `lspci -tv`. I am only interested in the network cards. `grep Network`, but there are other cases, which says, `Ethernet`.

```
$ lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-01.0-[01-04]----00.0-[02-04]--+-01.0-[03]--+-00.0  Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection
           |                               |            +-00.1  Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection
           |                               |            +-00.2  Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection
           |                               |            \-00.3  Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection
           |                               \-03.0-[04]--+-00.0  Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection
           |                                            \-00.1  Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation HD Graphics P530
           +-13.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Integrated Sensor Hub
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
           +-16.1  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #2
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode]
           +-1c.0-[05]----00.0  Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection
           +-1c.1-[06]----00.0  Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection
           +-1c.6-[07-08]----00.0-[08]----00.0  ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC
           \-1f.4  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus
```

Comment: Adding yet another grep or other command onto your already lengthy pipeline would almost certainly be the wrong approach. If you post the output of `lspci -tv | grep -E 'Gigabit Network|Gigabit Ether| Ethernet'` (i.e. before the final `| grep ...` in your question) and tell us what it is you want to do with THAT then I expect you'll get help.

Comment: Can you provide output of `lspci -tv` in your question

Comment: @EdMorton. Added.

Comment: @anubhava, added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
!/Network|Ethernet/ { next }
match($0,/.*\[([0-9]+)\]/,a) {
    nic = a[1]
}
match($0,/.*[+-\\]-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)  /,a) {
    print nic ":" a[1]
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
03:00.0
03:00.1
03:00.2
03:00.3
04:00.0
04:00.1
05:00.0
06:00.0
```

Comment: This works for most cases for me. I seem to have a degenerate case where it's not showing me the output, but that's for another question.